# Swagger does not detect optional strings in URL Parameters

Tags: routes, swagger, option-type

It seems Swagger is not able to detect optional URL parameters if it is of string format?

For example:

```
customers/{customerid}/loyalty/promotions/{memberid?}
GetListOfPromotions(int customerId, string memberid = "")
```

Is allowed when I tried in Fiddler (customers/1234/loyalty/promotions). But Swagger still marks it as **required**.

However, the following route is allowed in **BOTH** **Swagger** and **Fiddler**:

```
customers/{customerid}/locations/{locationid}/baskets/{basketId?}
GetBasket(int customerId, int locationId, long? basketId = null)
```

Is there anything special that needs to be done to correct optional string in Swagger?

Comment: "Swagger" is [not a single project](https://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/) - which exactly project do you mean?